# Redcar Install Direct Options

Tags: usb, jruby, redcar

Is there a way to direct the install of redcar to a user defined location other than a user home directory?

I have a jruby install on a USB drive, E:\jruby-1.6.2. Redcar installs the gems to the E:\jruby sub directory but then installs the user files to ~/ on c:.

Is there a way to direct it to e:\fakehome. I want to keep all installation files on my USB drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response from Matthew Scharley directly answers how this can be done for redcar.

For the moment it is hard coded. Thankfully it is easy to change:

https://github.com/redcar/redcar/blob/master/lib/redcar.rb#L211

Comment: The link is outdated as the file it points to has changed.  I believe that line 211 once pointed to the self.home_dir method, which is on line 268 at the time of this comment posting.  BTW, it parses a commandline switch now (/^--home-dir=(.*)/), so the original problem no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a Redcar-specific solution, but here is a general solution that may work for you.

**PROBLEM:**

The user has an application that installs application data files to a fixed location, but the user wants the files in a different location (such as a removable drive or a standardized app data directory).

**SOLUTION:**

Use a Junction Point or Symlink to simulate the presence of the pre-configured directory.

**STEPS:**

- install the application normally
- locate the pre-configured directory that you wish to have relocated (e.g. c:\users\foouser\appdata\fooapp)
- create an empty directory with the same name in your alternate desired location (e.g., e:\myusbdrive\appdata\fooapp)
- terminate the application you just installed if it is still running
- move all of the files out of the pre-configured directory and put them in the desired directory
- delete the toplevel pre-configured directory
- create a junction that points to the toplevel pre-configured directory you just deleted from the alternate desired location
- restart the application and use it normally, making sure that it still behaves normally.

If all goes well you should be finished.

Here i a link to a junction creator (for older versions of Windows (TM))

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768

HTH